# How to load the specified columns of text file in DolphinDB?

Tags: sql, database, dolphindb

There are 15 columns in my text file: symbol, permno, datetime, price1, ... , price6, qty1, ..., qty6. I would like to load the following columns into DolphinDB: symbol, permno, datetime, price1, qty1. Now I just load all columns into DolphinDB and then select the columns what I need, but the text file is large and it will out of memory.

Here is my code:

```
stock=loadText("/home/summer/data/trades_20180912.csv")
t=select symbol, permno, datetime, price1, qty1 from stock
```

Answer (score 0):

One can use a schema table to specify which column to import. Below is the full code

```
schemaTBL = extractTextSchema("/home/summer/data/trades_20180912.csv")
update schemaTBL set col = rowNo(name)
schemaTBL = select * from schemaTBL where col in `symbol`permno`datetime`price1`qty1
stock = loadText("/home/summer/data/trades_20180912.csv",,schemaTBL)
```